# Ruby 1.8.7 world writable check? File.world_writable? is only 1.9.x

Tags: ruby, macos

I need to check a specific file to see if it is world writable or not.  In 1.9.x, there is [a handy check for this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-world_writable-3F), but this check does not exist in 1.8.7.  I need to write this script in 1.8.7 for compatibility reasons.

Is there a good method for doing this check in 1.8.7 that I am missing, or will I need to roll my own way of doing it using stat?

*edit*
This is what I've come up with so far.  Kind of hacky and bad, but it works:

```
def world_writable?(file)
  write_bit = Integer(sprintf("%o", File.stat(file).mode)[-1,1])
  if [2, 3, 6, 7].include?(write_bit)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

if world_writable?('/Users/nate/Desktop/scriptrunnertest/test1.sh')
  puts "World writable"
else
  puts "Not World Writable"
end
```

I am quite new to ruby, so be gentle.

*edit2* nevermind, that doesn't even work.

*edit3* fixed it

Answer (score 3):

You could get the `stat` object for the file, and examine its `mode` member...

```
world_writable = File.stat("testfile").mode == 0x100777
```

You should be able to add this to `File`...

```
class File
    def self.world_writable? path
        permissions = File.stat(path).mode
        permissions == 0x100777 && permissions || nil
    end
end
```

[RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/07619).

Comment: When I try world_writable = File.stat("testfile").mode == 0x100777

world_writable is always false, even if the testfile is 777.  I should be able to use that one liner as a quick test, correct?

Comment: What do the permissions tell you with `ls -l` ?

Comment: What does `File.stat("testfile").mode` return? You can read the octal with `to_s(16)`.

Comment: > File.stat("test1.sh").mode
=> 33279
>> File.stat("test1.sh").mode.to_s(16)
=> "81ff"
>>